# Displaying metadata for multiple authors in Elementor's "widget posts"

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I'm facing a little issue with WordPress, and I could really use your help. You see, I'm not very experienced with coding, so I'm hoping you can lend me a hand in the right direction.

I'm using the PublishPress Authors plugin to have multiple authors on my website, and Elementor as my page builder. But here's the catch: when I create a page with the latest posts using Elementor's "widget posts" feature, it only displays metadata for one author. However, I want to show metadata for all the authors associated with the posts.

Now, here's where I'm struggling. I think the problem lies in the code, but I'm not sure which file to look at or where exactly to make the changes. It would be fantastic if you could guide me on this!

I've heard that the PublishPress Authors plugin has this cool "get_coauthors" function that can fetch an array of co-authors for a post. That sounds like the key to the solution! But I could use some assistance in locating the code that needs modification and making the necessary changes.

Thank you so much for your kind assistance and support. I truly appreciate your patience with a beginner like me!

Attempted: Multiple author metadata display.
Expected: All authors' metadata.
Actual: Single author displayed.

Comment: Have you tried reaching out to the Elementor support team yet? If someone can answer this question for sure it's them.

Comment: Thank you. Since I have the pro version of Elementor, I reached out them shortly before creating this post. For now, I have to wait for their response. In the meantime, I'll also see if anyone here knows how to do it.

Comment: Sadly Elementor support team can't help me:
"By default, wordpress gives you the opportunity to add one author. Elementor works on the basis of the default wordpress functionality in this case.
In this case, adding an additional author won't be possible with the elementor manual tools, it will require additional custom code/usage of the different third-party widgets.
Please note that we do not provide users with custom code; we also do not provide future troubleshooting for custom code."